# Expand bib entries with crossref

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I have two bib files: publications-crossref.bib and ref.bib. The first file contains crossref(s) to the second file. I want to expand the first file publications-crossref.bib with the second file. For example, I give an entry of publications-crossref.bib, other of ref.bib, and my expected output:

publications-crossref.bib:

```
@inproceedings{key:icfp2006,
  author = {john wayne},
  title  = {Very Good},
  crossref = {icfp2006},
  pages = {580--681},
}
```

ref.bib:

```
@proceedings{icfp2006,
  key = {ICFP 2006},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 11th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Functional Programming (ICFP 2006)},
  year = 2006,
  address = {Portland, Oregon, USA},
  month = sep,
  publisher = acm,
}
```

output.bib:

```
@inproceedings{key:icfp2006,
      author = {john wayne},
      title  = {Very Good},
      booktitle = {Proceedings of the 11th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Functional Programming (ICFP 2006)},
      year = 2006,
      address = {Portland, Oregon, USA},
      month = sep,
      publisher = acm,
      pages = {580--681},
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality required is provided by the `bibexport` tool, and the command

```
bibexport -ec ref.bib -es string.bib -n -o output.bib -a publication-crossref.bib
```

- the `-e` switch instructs to use an additional file (for both strings and crossefs, or `-ec` for only crossfefs, and `-es` for only strings);
- the `-n` switch is for not including crossers in the output (specified by the `-o` switch);
- finally, the `-a` switch is to consider all references in the `bib` file.

`bibexport`, by default, exports only the standard fields (those defined in `plain.bst`), but it is possible to add and remove additional fields, but one has to modify the `export.bst` file.

Comment: Perfect!... But I realize that I also depend on another file: "string.bib". To sum up, I have my main file "publication-crossref.bib", but this bib file depends on "ref.bib" (cross-references) and "string.bib". 

In addition, Is it possible to remove some fields ("key" from "ref.bib") when the command is executing? Thanks a lot!